# How to get value from one table and add it to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, 1 look like
**tableA**

```
id name value
------------------
1  Joe  22
2  John 50
3  Joe  38
4  Joe  10
5  John 20
```

I need to add all the value of value with same name from tableA and store in the tableB like this
**tableB**

```
id name value
---------------
1  Joe  70
2 John  70
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: So, first of all, welcome to StackOverflow. What did you try so far?

Comment: um really new to mysql so i dnt kno how to do it ...

Comment: i am able to get the sum by "SELECT name, sum(value) as Total_value from `table1` group by name" bt cant save it in table 2

Comment: I suggest it's probably not a good idea to store that information in another table. It will be outdated as soon as you make changes to TableA. You can get the information you want at any time using a GROUP BY query. There's no need to duplicate information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tableb already exists, you can insert the data like this:

```
insert into tableb(id, name, value)
select min(id), name, sum(value)
from tablea
group by name;
```

Comment: No, you are not giving any hints. Your answer contains only code, there is not explanation, no rationale.

Answer (score -1):

Hi use (Select * INTO ) like this.

> SELECT * INTO Table2
>   FROM Table1

Comment: Nope, you can't use select into for this in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into tableb(id, name, value)
select id, name, sum(value)
from tablea
group by name,id;
```

Comment: Nope. You'd insert 5 rows from sample data because there are 5 unique id values. And if you fix your mistake, your answer will be the same as an existing one - so I suggest you delete it instead.